# How I do to roll the text to the bottom?

Tags: android-layout, text, slider

I'm programming on ADK and I got one screen with a text at a huge font so the whole text can't appear on the screen. I want to know to do slide the finger up and see the text below, sliding it as we do with normal texts on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your TextView inside ScrollView in XML like:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="txt2"/>

</ScrollView>
```

**OR** If You don't need to use a `ScrollView` actually.

Just set the

```
     android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
     android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your `TextView` in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
   yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

in your code.

It scrolls automatically without any issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but after doing the 1st option, Eclipse reclaims about:
This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless. My code is like: 
<RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView>
<TextView/>
<ScrollView/>
<RelativeLayout/>

What could be wrong? Thanks since now.

Comment: Its because of `ScrollView` can not be added as childview. There should only a single root view and it must contain a singly child view always.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I still didn't get what to do. I want to do a first screen that gets a typed text through an intent and sends it to other screen, but it happens the text is bigger than the screen. Doing only  <ScrollView> <TextView/> <ScrollView/>  didn't work. If you could help I'd appreciate a lot.

Comment: Can you add some code ? Also a screenshot what actually you want to implement? Its bit difficult to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom listview! Like so : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_overview